# How to pass 2 javascript events in one click?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass 2 javascript events in one click, I put 2 of them into `href` and `onclick`. But when I click, it always executes the `onclick` action. Click again or a third time, the `href` action gets executed. I do not know how it was like this.

How do I to solve it?

If I combine 2 javascript events in one part(href or onclick). is it could run well? how to?

thanks.

```
<a href="javascript:function1('value1')" onclick="javascript:function2('value2')">
```

Comment: To clarify, you're not trying to pass two events. You've got one event, the click, and you want to call two functions when that event occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="function1('value1'); function2('value2'); return false;">
```

Note that you do not need to put "javascript:" in the onclick event. And it is generally better to use onclick rather than href to execute javascript.

You could even change `href="#"` to link to a page saying you need javascript enabled. `return false;` will cancel the link if javascript is working.

Answer (score 1):

you'd better not use dom level0 event.
in jquery you can do:

```
 $('element').bind('click',function(){
  function1();
  function2(); })
```

not in jquery, you can use
http://dean.edwards.name/my/events.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="function1('value1'); function2('value2');">
```